# Python 3.1.1 with --enable-shared : will not build any extensions

Tags: python, compilation, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

Summary: Building Python 3.1 on RHEL 5.3 64 bit with `--enable-shared` fails to compile all extensions.  Building "normal" works fine without any problems.

**Please note** that this question may seem to blur the line between programming and system administration.  However, I believe that because it has to deal directly with getting language support in place, and it very much has to do with supporting the process of programming, that I would cross-post it here.  Also at: https://serverfault.com/questions/73196/python-3-1-1-with-enable-shared-will-not-build-any-extensions.  Thank you!

**Problem:**

Building Python 3.1 on RHEL 5.3 64 bit with `--enable-shared` fails to compile all extensions.  Building "normal" works fine without any problems.

I can build python 3.1 just fine, but when built as a shared library, it emits many warnings (see below), and refuses to build any of the `c` based modules.  Despite this failure, I can still build mod_wsgi 3.0c5 against it, and run it under apache.  Needless to say, the functionality of Python is greatly reduced...

Interesting to note that Python 3.2a0 (from svn) compiles fine with --enable-shared, and mod_wsgi compiles fine against it.  But when starting apache, I get:

`Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr`

The project that this is for is a long-term project, so I'm okay with alpha quality software if needed.  Here are some more details on the problem.

**Host:**

- Dell PowerEdge
- Intel Xenon
- RHEL 5.3 64bit
- Nothing "special"

**Build:**

- Python 3.1.1 source distribution
- Works fine with `./configure`
- Does not work fine with `./configure --enable-shared`

(`export CFLAGS="-fPIC"` has been done)

**make output**

---

`gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_weakref.c -o Modules/_weakref.o`

---

`building 'bz2' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -IInclude -I/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1 -c /home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.1/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.o
gcc -pthread -shared -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.1/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.o -L/usr/local/lib -L. -lbz2 -lpython3.1 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.1/bz2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.1.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against 'a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

---

```
Failed to build these modules:
_bisect            _codecs_cn         _codecs_hk
_codecs_iso2022    _codecs_jp         _codecs_kr
_codecs_tw         _collections       _csv
_ctypes            _ctypes_test       _curses
_curses_panel      _dbm               _elementtree
_gdbm              _hashlib           _heapq
_json              _lsprof            _multibytecodec
_multiprocessing   _pickle            _random
_socket            _sqlite3           _ssl
_struct            _testcapi          array
atexit             audioop            binascii
bz2                cmath              crypt
datetime           fcntl              grp
itertools          math               mmap
nis                operator           ossaudiodev
parser             pyexpat            readline
resource           select             spwd
syslog             termios            time
unicodedata        zlib
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something is wrong with your build environment. It is picking up a libpython3.1.a from `/usr/local/lib`; this confuses the error messages. It tries linking with that library, which fails - however, it shouldn't have tried that in the first place, since it should have used the libpython that it just built. I recommend taking the Python 3.1 installation in `/usr/local` out of the way.

You don't show in your output whether a libpython3.1.so.1.0 was created in the build tree; it would be important to find out whether it exists, how it was linked, and what symbols it has exported.

Comment: Hi Martin,  I'd like to comment that this 100% fixed the problem I was having.  Thank you!  Do you have any idea why it would be looking in /usr/local instead of /home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/...?

Comment: Re-reading the linker line, it becomes clear: `-L/usr/local/lib` is before `-L.`

Comment: For me, this was a problem with the PATH variable pointing to another version of python.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/lib has been added to the library include path at compile time:

-L/usr/local/lib -L.

Its common for compile time to look in multiple 'common' paths for libraries (/usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, ./, etc) but also, it's possibly picking up /usr/local/lib from the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH and tacking it on to the build command.

Comment: Interesting... How would you instruct it to look in "." FIRST, before anywhere else?

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable shouldn't be used in that way, so if it is using directories from LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add to compiler flags, it is arguably broken.