# mod_wsgi on archlinux with python 3.2

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, archlinux, python-3.2

I actually had mod_wsgi working with python3.1, but after updating some software... it no longer works.

I followed these instructions for python3.1 modified slightly for 3.2:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi

and while it seems to build/install ok, trying to start apache give me the error :

Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr

just as this guy got: 
[Python 3.1.1 with --enable-shared : will not build any extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547310/python-3-1-1-with-enable-shared-will-not-build-any-extensions)

Any help would be appreciated.

I am a linux noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The released versions of mod_wsgi cannot be used with Python 3.2. You must currently use source code directly from subversion repository for mod_wsgi. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/source/checkout

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm, got a new trunk, then ./configure, make, make install. restarted apache and was good to go. thanks.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton : excuse me my freind , what version of wsgi should I use for python 3.2

Comment: You would be well advised not to use Python 3.2. The first really usable version of Python 3.X was Python 3.3 as it restored some features which had been dropped from Python 3. Anyway, have you actually tried the latest version? https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi