# Python 3.1.1 with --enable-shared : will not build any extensions

Tags: linux, python, compilation

Summary: Building Python 3.1 on RHEL 5.3 64 bit with --enable-shared fails to compile all extensions. Building "normal" works fine without any problems.

**Please note** that this question may seem to blur the line between programming and system administration.  However, I believe that because it has to deal directly with OS issues and Programming issues, I would cross-post it on both StackOverflow and ServerFault.  Also at [Python 3.1.1 with --enable-shared : will not build any extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547310/python-3-1-1-with-enable-shared-will-not-build-any-extensions).  Thanks!

**Problem:**

Building Python 3.1 on RHEL 5.3 64 bit with `--enable-shared` fails to compile all extensions.  Building "normal" works fine without any problems.

I can build python 3.1 just fine, but when built as a shared library, it emits many warnings (see below), and refuses to build any of the `c` based modules.  Despite this failure, I can still build mod_wsgi 3.0c5 against it, and run it under apache.  Needless to say, the functionality of Python is greatly reduced...

Interesting to note that Python 3.2a0 (from svn) compiles fine with --enable-shared, and mod_wsgi compiles fine against it.  But when starting apache, I get:

`Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr`

The project that this is for is a long-term project, so I'm okay with alpha quality software if needed.  Here are some more details on the problem.

**Host:**

- Dell PowerEdge
- Intel Xenon
- RHEL 5.3 64bit
- Nothing "special"

**Build:**

- Python 3.1.1 source distribution
- Works fine with `./configure`
- Does not work fine with `./configure --enable-shared`

(`export CFLAGS="-fPIC"` has been done)

**make output**

---

`gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_weakref.c -o Modules/_weakref.o`

---

`building 'bz2' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -IInclude -I/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1 -c /home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.1/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.o
gcc -pthread -shared -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.1/home/build/RPMBUILD/BUILD/Python-3.1.1/Modules/bz2module.o -L/usr/local/lib -L. -lbz2 -lpython3.1 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.1/bz2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.1.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against 'a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

---

```
Failed to build these modules:
_bisect            _codecs_cn         _codecs_hk
_codecs_iso2022    _codecs_jp         _codecs_kr
_codecs_tw         _collections       _csv
_ctypes            _ctypes_test       _curses
_curses_panel      _dbm               _elementtree
_gdbm              _hashlib           _heapq
_json              _lsprof            _multibytecodec
_multiprocessing   _pickle            _random
_socket            _sqlite3           _ssl
_struct            _testcapi          array
atexit             audioop            binascii
bz2                cmath              crypt
datetime           fcntl              grp
itertools          math               mmap
nis                operator           ossaudiodev
parser             pyexpat            readline
resource           select             spwd
syslog             termios            time
unicodedata        zlib
```

Comment: (1) are you sure you cleaned everything out when trying the -fPIC option?  the error above suggests it was not used while building libpython (you show the creation of bz2module.o).  (2) have you tried `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` for the modules (along with `-fPIC` for libpython)?  [i have no idea what it does, just know it is some obscure magic sometimes used in such cases]

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Python 3.1.1 with --enable-shared : will not build any extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547310/11725753).